# Rewrite the URL in Nginx to redirect to only the pathname

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to allow users who have only intranet access to access a single site on the internet using Nginx. My current nginx configuration is

```
 server {
 listen aproxy.com:80;
 rewrite_log on;
 location ~ ^/bproxy {
 if ($args != "")
 {
    return 302 http://$args;
 }
```

This allows me to redirect from aproxy.com/bproxy?www.somewebsite.com to www.somewebsite.com, but shows the URL as www.somewebsite.com. I would like to be able to send the user from aproxy.com/bproxy/www.somewebsite.com (not as args) to www.somewebsite.com without the change being visible in the URL bar. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You may try [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) instead of `return`:

```
location ~ ^/bproxy/(.*) {
    resolver        8.8.8.8;  #set DNS resolver (by Google) to prevent "no resolver defined to resolve <domain>" error
    proxy_pass      http://$1;
}
```

But keep in mind that if remote page contains a link like

```
<a href="some-path">Link</a>
```

the link URL becomes

```
http://aproxy.com/bproxy/some-path
```

and

```
<a href="/some-path">Link</a>
```

becomes

```
http://aproxy.com/some-path
```

The same goes to any resource within a page (images, js, css, etc.), so the web page's behavior might be broken.

Maybe you should get rid of `/bproxy` path and let full `aproxy.com` domain to be a proxy itself.

**Update:**

You may also try to use [`server_name`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) directive:

```
server {
    listen         127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name    aproxy.com;
    #...
}
```

**Update 2 - server that proxies to specific site only (without https support):**

```
server {
    listen          127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name     aproxy.com;

    location / {
        resolver        8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass      http://stackoverflow.com;
    }
}
```

Thus, browsing to `http://aproxy.com/questions`, you get the same result as `http://stackoverflow.com/questions`

**Note:**

If you want to make this proxy be visible in your local network, replace `127.0.0.1` with server's local IP (it might be something like `192.168.1.10`)

Comment: That's how I was doing it to start with, but unless I explicitly put in listen aproxy.com:80, nginx was listening on 0.0.0.0:80

Comment: I was able to get it to redirect to the correct URL, but the URL in the bar is still the new website (www.somewebsite.com) and not aproxy.com/brpoxy/www.somewebsite.com

Comment: Try `listen 127.0.0.1:80;`. So what happens when you browse `http://aproxy.com/bproxy/stackoverflow.com` having the config like in my post?

Comment: I get an error message saying Couldn't find aproxy.com. This error is coming on a page with the Stackexchange image. But the URL in the bar remains http://aproxy.com/bproxy/stackoverflow.com. In the access.log, I see that the request was  "GET /bproxy/stackoverflow.com HTTP/1.1"

Comment: Don't know the reason of such behavior. Here is what I have http://i.stack.imgur.com/5c3Hb.png (`map.com` is a domain name I use instead of `aproxy.com`). Can you provide a screenshot of your page? BTW, have you written `127.0.0.1  aproxy.com` in your `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: It looks like you have `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` directive. Am I right? If I write this line in my config I have the same result as on your screenshot

Comment: I have proxy_set_header Host $host.. and you are right, when I take it out, I get the same error page you get. But do you know how to resolve that error?

Comment: You may set `aproxy.com` for proxying to specific site only (and you don't have to set a path, like `/bproxy`). Take a look at my Update 2. This is the best solution I can suggest.

Comment: So the problem is that the domain is dynamic. So I can't really set it to a single specific site.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't help you more than that :( I'm not a professional sysadmin (rather programmer). Maybe you will get more help at http://serverfault.com/ - sysadmins' analog of StackOverflow. I really wish you good luck with this :)

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help @CuriousGuy . I feel like I'm really close to the actual solution.